# Moving an ImageView in the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

I am trying to move an ImageView according to the buttons pressed. For the moment I am trying to move the ImageView Up and Down, the Down thing works perfectly but the problem is when I try to make it go up. When the ImageView isn't at its initial position the ImageView goes up perfectly (until it reaches its initial position) but when it is at its initial position it just goes up one time and then when I press the up button again it goes down to its initial position.

(Just to let you know, the orientation of the screen is on landscape)

So, to move my ImageView up I just lower the value of translationY 
`imageView.translationY = imageView.translationY.absoluteValue - 25`

I tried using `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat()` but the imageView goes back to its initial position after the animation.

In the layout I am just using a constraint layout and I constrain the ImageView at the centre of the screen.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think constraint layout will be good for this case. I have created a sample project to check this out. This uses `MotionLayout` with `MotionScene`

The Idea is to create **MotionLayout** as your parent layout and then define the Childers to animate in your case its **ImageView** here is sample layout file. Use this file in some activity or some fragment to see in action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/up_down_descriptor">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivStar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_outline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="up"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivStar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="Down"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivStar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

and you define a layout description file **up_down_descriptor** in **res/xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/down"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/center"
        app:duration="2000">

        <OnClick
            app:clickAction="toggle"
            app:targetId="@id/btnDown" />

    </Transition>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/up"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/center"
        app:duration="2000">

        <OnClick
            app:clickAction="toggle"
            app:targetId="@id/btnUp" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/center">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/ivStar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/down">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/ivStar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/up">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/ivStar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

MotionLayout will take care of the rest of the things.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what you advised me but the fact is that I don't want the imageView to go directly from the centre of the screen to the edges of it but it must do more steps before reaching the edges (like moving a certain amount of pixels each time you press the button).